# JiBX/PiBX SOAP binding example

Tags: php, xml, soap, binding, jibx

I was trying to find some examples how to write binding.xml with JiBX/PiBX for following SOAP response but with no luck. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
       <ns6:getDataResp xmlns:ns6="http://domain.com/response/data/">
       <s3:requestId xmlns:s3="http://domain.com/entity/">12</s3:requestId>
       <s4:errorCode xmlns:s3="http://domain.com/entity1/">0</s4:errorCode>
           <ns6:dataResp>
               <ns5:Data>Some string data</ns5:Data>
           </ns6:dataResp>
       </ns6:getDataResp>
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JiBX you're in luck. You have a couple of options:

1. The apache cxf project has a databinding module for JiBX. You can use one of the open-source web servers such as servicemix to do your SOAP handling. This means you only have to bind the message schema (getDataResp in your example) with JiBX. You can find a nice example, [here](http://blog.tourgeek.com/2012/04/creating-soap-and-rest-services-for.html).
2. JiBX has it's own web server called [JiBX/WS](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/jibxws/index.html). It will also do all the SOAP handling for you.

I hope this helps!

Don
JiBX contributor